# Is there anyway to restrict an env variable to readonly

Tags: unix, ssh, telnet

I am using the following in openssh/telnet code, which sets the user environment.

```
setenv("TEST_ENV", "testing", 1);
```

But this can be modified by the user after login, is there anyway to make it read-only env variable?

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm not aware of any way of making a process's environment read-only.

You are aware, I trust, that a process can't change its *parent's* environment, and that a process has complete freedom to set the initial environment of any processes it in turn creates.  It might be worth being a little more detailed about what you want to do, or what you want to stop a program being able to do.

Some OSs have fairly elaborate sandboxing support in the kernel (I know OS X has, for example, but it won't be the only one), and these *might* be able to control access to `getenv`.  But that's obviously platform-specific.